# Meu programa só executa o primeiro if?

Tags: c, c++

Eu preciso elaborar um algorítimo que que receba 3 valores reais e que verifique se esses valores podem ser os comprimentos dos lados de um triangulo, e neste caso, retornar qual o tipo de triangulo formado.

Para que `x`, `y` e `z` formem um triangulo e necessário que a seguinte propriedade seja satisfeita: o comprimento de cada lado de um triangulo e menor do que a soma do comprimento dos outros dois lados.

Qualquer valor que eu ponho no meu algoritmo ele responde como escaleno que é o primeiro `if`, o que tem errado nele?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(float x, float y, float z)  
{  
float a,b,c;
float tri;

a=x+y;  
b=x+z;  
c=y+z;  

if(a>z || b>y || c>x)  
{  
    if(x==y && x==z && y==z)  
    {  
        tri=1;  
    }    
    else  
    {  
        if((x==y && y==z) || (x==z && y==z) || (x==y && x==z))  
        {  
            tri=2;    
        }    
        if (x!=y && x!=z && y!=z )  
        {  
            tri=3;  
        }  
    }  
}  
    return tri;  
}  

int main()  
{  
    float x,y,z;  
    float tri;  
    printf("Informe 3 valores reais: \n");  
    scanf("%f %f %f",&x,&y,&z);  

    tri=func(x,y,z);  

    if (tri==1)  
    {  
        printf("O triangulo eh escaleno.\n");  
    }  
    if(tri==2)  
    {  
        printf("O triangulo eh isoceles\n");  
    }  
    if(tri==3)  
    {  
        printf("O triangulo eh escaleno\n");  
    }  

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: O correto é `isósceles` e não `isoceles`.. **#valorizeoportugues**

Comment: Como vc sabe que ele entra apenas no primeiro IF se tem dois IF's com a mesma resposta?

Comment: Só um detalhe: a função retorna int, mas a variável "tri" é do tipo float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltou considerar o caso em que `x`, `y` e `z` não fazem parte de um triângulo:

```
int func(float x, float y, float z)
{
    int retorno = 0; // zero é o caso em que não é triângulo

    float somaxy = x + y;
    float somaxz = x + z;
    float somayz = y + z;

    if (somaxy > z || somaxz > y || somayz > x)
    {
        // É um triângulo; verificar de qual tipo agora.
        if (x == y && y == z)
        {
            retorno = 1; // É triângulo equilátero
        }
        else if (x == y || x == z || y == z)
        {
            retorno = 2; // É triângulo isósceles
        }
        else
        {
            retorno = 3; // É triângulo regular
        }
    }

    return retorno;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float x, y, z;

    printf("Digite os lados do triangulo separados por espacos e, no final, de Enter\n");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &x, &y, &z);

    printf("Os valores informados... ");
    switch (func(x, y, z))
    {
        case 0:
            printf("nao sao de um triangulo!\n");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("sao de um triangulo equilatero\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("sao de um triangulo isosceles\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("sao de um triangulo regular\n");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No final da função `*main()*`:
`if (tri==1)` ---> O triângulo é equilátero, e não escaleno!
Verifique o `printf().`

A condição:

```
if((x==y && y==z) || (x==z && y==z) || (x==y && x==z))
```

é um teste para triângulo equilátero que já tinha sido testada no "if" anterior.

Para triângulo isósceles seria: `if(x==y || y==z || x==z)`.