# Erro logico ao utilizar If/else

Tags: c

Estou tentando fazer com que meu programa identifique um triangulo e me diga se ele é Equilátero, isósceles ou escaleno. Sou iniciante na linguagem C, então criei uma estrutura com If/Else para analisar as condições para identificar se o valor digitado corresponde a um triangulo, se sim me dizer que tipo de triangulo corresponde e se não corresponder a um triangulo informar que os dados digitados não correspondem.

Porem meu problema é que qualquer valor digitado o programa diz que o valor não corresponde a um triangulo.

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar a entender o meu erro??

```
int main () {

    //VARIAVEIS

    float A = 0;
    float B = 0;
    float C = 0;


    printf ("\nCALCULANDO UM TRIANGULO!\n");
    printf ("\nDIGITE OS VALORES DOS CATETOS:\n");
    getch();

    printf ("\nDIGITE O VALOR DE (A):\n");
    scanf("%f", &A);
    printf ("\nDIGITE O VALOR DE (B):\n");
    scanf("%f", &B);
    printf ("\nDIGITE O VALOR DE (C):\n");
    scanf("%f", &C);

    printf ("\nOS VALORES DIGITADOS: %.2fcm %.2fcm %.2fcm\n", A , B , C);
    printf ("\nPRESSIONE ENTER...\n");
    getch ();

        if ((A + B < C) || (B + C < A) || (A + C < B)) {

            printf ("\nVAMOS CALCULAR O TRIANGULO\n");


            if ((A == B) && (B == C)) {

                printf ("\nTRIANGULO EQUILATERO!\n");

            }
            else {

                if((A == B) || (A == C) || (B == C)) {

                    printf ("\nTRIANGULO ISOCELES!\n");

                }
                else {

                    printf ("\nTRIANGULO ESCALENO!\n");

                }

            }

        }
        else {

            printf ("\nVALORES NAO CORRESPONDEM A UM TRIANGULO!\n");

        }
```

Comment: O seu código parece que ficou incompleto. Confirme como o tem no seu editor e como ficou aqui na pergunta para que fique igual.

Comment: pode mandar o codigo completo?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Meu programa só executa o primeiro if?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/302256/meu-programa-s%c3%b3-executa-o-primeiro-if)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só irá existir um triângulo se, somente se, os seus lados obedeceram à seguinte regra: um de seus lados deve ser maior que o valor absoluto (módulo) da diferença dos outros dois lados e menor que a soma dos outros dois lados. Veja o resumo da regra abaixo:

```
| b – c | < a < b + c

| a – c | < b < a + c

| a – b | < c < a – b
```

Com as medidas a=5cm, b=10cm e c=9cm, podemos formar um triângulo?

```
|10 – 9| < 5 < 10 + 9 
1 < 5 <19 (VERDADEIRO) 

|9 – 5| < 10 < 9 + 5 
4 < 10 < 14 (VERDADEIRO)

|5 – 10| < 9 < 10 + 5 
5 < 9 < 15 (VERDADEIRO)
```

> veja aplicando esses valores a sua condição:

```
((A + B < C) || (B + C < A) || (A + C < B))

((5 + 10 < 9) || (10 + 9 < 5) || (5 + 9 < 10))
```

> totalmente errada!!

Com as medidas 5cm, 10cm e 4cm, podemos formar um triângulo?

```
|10 – 4| < 5 < 10 + 4 
6 < 5 < 14 (FALSO)
```

> Quando uma condição não obedece à regra não é possível existir um triângulo.

Equilátero: 3 lados iguais `a == b && b == c`

Isósceles: pelo menos dois de seus lados tem medidas iguais `a==b || a==c || b==c`

Escaleno: 3 lados diferentes `a !=b && b !=c`

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que todo o seu problema está nesta linha:

```
    if ((A + B < C) || (B + C < A) || (A + C < B)) {
```

Eu colocaria assim:

```
    if ( (C < (A+B)) && (A < (B+C)) && (B < (A+C)) ) {
```

Eu coloquei parêntesis nas operações por conta da precedência. Além disso as três condições devem ser verdadeiras, já que nenhum lado deve ser maior que a soma dos outros dois.

Outro ponto importante: cuidado com as comparações com tipos `float` . Devido a maneira como os números são armazenados, 3 nem sempre será igual a 3 ;)

Por último, um refinamento interessante é não permitir lados iguais a zero.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! consegui solucionar meu problema! Grato!! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Este teste:

```
if ((A + B < C) || (B + C < A) || (A + C < B)) {
```

é inválido para testar se os 3 valores podem representar um triângulo.
Em um triângulo cada lado é menor que a soma dos outros dois e não maior como você testou.
Além disso a medida de cada um dos lados tem que ser positiva.
O teste correto é:

```
if ((a > 0) && (b > 0) && (c > 0) && (a<(b+c)) && (b<(a+c)) && (c<(a+b))) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse seu conjunto de if/else é bastante confuso, não entendi muito bem a necessidade do primeiro if, mas uma coisa que pode te ajudar são o if/else if onde basicamente se não é uma condição, pode ser outra condição até terminar. Exemplo:

```
if(Primeira Condição)
{
 Executa esse trecho
} 
else if(Segunda Condição)
{
 Executa esse trecho
}
else < - Quando acabarem todas as condições 
{
 Executa esse trecho
}
```

---

Fiz isso no seu código para você ver. Repare que na segunda condição eu limito que apenas a comparação entre a variável C precisa ser diferente para poder dar o resultado de um triângulo isósceles. É claro, você pode colocar mais condições com os operadores lógicos "&&" (E) e "||" (OU). Dá uma olhada:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

//VARIAVEIS

float A = 0;
float B = 0;
float C = 0;


printf ("\nCALCULANDO UM TRIANGULO!\n");
printf ("\nDIGITE OS VALORES DOS CATETOS:\n");
getch();

printf ("\nDIGITE O VALOR DE (A):\n");
scanf("%f", &A);
printf ("\nDIGITE O VALOR DE (B):\n");
scanf("%f", &B);
printf ("\nDIGITE O VALOR DE (C):\n");
scanf("%f", &C);

printf ("\nOS VALORES DIGITADOS: %.2fcm %.2fcm %.2fcm\n", A , B , C);
printf ("\nPRESSIONE ENTER...\n");
getch ();

 printf ("\nVAMOS CALCULAR O TRIANGULO\n");

 if(A == B && A == C && C == B)
 {
     printf("\nTriângulo Equilatero");
 } else if(A == B && C != A && C != B)
 {
     printf("\nTriângulo Isósceles");
 }
 else
 {
     printf("Triângulo Escaleno");
 }
 }
```

Comment: se A é igual a B e A é igual a C esse C igual a B é desnecessário né não?

Comment: Sim, de fato foi desnecessário.

Answer (score 1):

Dei uma pesquisada. Não precisa exatamente de um calculo se é só a verificação. Se tiver dúvida só perguntar.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void calcula_triangulo(int A, int B, int C){
printf ("\nVAMOS CALCULAR O TRIANGULO\n");

if (A == B && B == C) {
printf ("\nTRIANGULO EQUILATERO!\n");
}
  else if(A == B && A != C && B != C) // Agora entra na condição {
  printf ("\nTRIANGULO ISOCELES!\n");
 }
    else {
    printf ("\nTRIANGULO ESCALENO!\n");
}


}




main(){
float A=0;
float B=0;
float C=0;


printf ("\nCALCULANDO UM TRIANGULO!\n");
printf ("\nDIGITE OS VALORES DOS CATETOS:\n");
getch();

printf ("\nDIGITE O VALOR DE (A):\n");
scanf("%f", &A);
printf ("\nDIGITE O VALOR DE (B):\n");
scanf("%f", &B);
printf ("\nDIGITE O VALOR DE (C):\n");
scanf("%f", &C);

printf ("\nOS VALORES DIGITADOS: %.2fcm %.2fcm %.2fcm\n", A , B , C);
printf ("\nPRESSIONE ENTER...\n");
calcula_triangulo(A,B,C);
```

}